# Performance spike on adding an object in VeticalLayoutGroup

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm making a chat that can have lots of messages inside and the container for these messages uses `VerticalLayoutGroup`.
As more messages in VLG as more CPU load on adding new message.
It seems that each time when I'm adding a new message into VLG it calculates something but for all messages and not only for new one.
So is there any way to fix it?

There is next hierarchy:

Canvas

```
-Scroll View
--Viewport
---Content (Vertical Layout Group, Content Size Fitter)
----Panel (Image) lots of panels like this
```

[image]

Comment: I guess it has to recalculate the relation for all objects that are already part of the vertical layout group to update their spacing which will take longer the more objects are in this group. To reduce the calculations you would have to reduce the number of elements, e.g. by merging them into one or maybe having older ones being stored in another subcontainer (empty gameobject) would do the trick.

Comment: I just checked it and yeah, merging elements into one subcontainer works, but it breaks the position of the elements. So how to preserve the position after merging to make elements look like before?

Comment: I have already figured out it xD it's easy xD

Comment: nope, it's still makes performance spikes, but now it needs more elements and the profiler shows that elements that in subcontainer still take part in some calculations http://puu.sh/p4HTS/b124496cb7.png  51 - it's the number of elements in subcontainer